# Why does my size variable have an error even though i clearly stated that its a constant integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, static

I am trying to create a integer function that returns arrays to int main after doing some calculations, for some reason my size variable is showing that it is not constant even though i stated in the parameter that it is a const int. My int temp[size] is the one showing the issue, the error states expression must have a constant value, the value of parameter "size" (declared at line 5) cannot be used as a constant. , this is my code, i cannot change the namespace or the libraries in the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int reArrangeArray(int A[], const int size) 
{
    int temp[size];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = size - 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0) 
        {
            temp[j] = A[i];
            j++;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp[k] = A[i];
            k--;
        }
    }

    // transfer the elements in temp into the original array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        A[i] = temp[i];
        return A[i];
    }
    
    
}
```

I tried initialising const int size outside the function, yet the error persisted.

basically what i want this code to do is rearrange integer arrays so that the even numbers are in front and the odd will be at the back, the initial array comes from int main, i ran this code on visual studio 2022 fyi.
for e.g.
1 2 3 4 5 6
after arranging
2 4 6 1 3 5

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could just use `std::partition` for this, it literally  does what you ask if given the right predicate:

https://godbolt.org/z/hnqzqo38M

Comment: I can also say that `return A[i];` is a bit nonsense to do in the MIDDLE of your loop.

Also, you can't in C++ do things like `int temp[size];` since size while a constant, is not a COMPILE TIME constant (that is, it's not necessarily known before runtime)

Comment: You should use a dynamic memory to allocate the array temp[size] at runtime on the heap. Otherwise you can use the std::vector which can be incremented and decremented at runtime.

Comment: `void reArrangeArray(int A[], const int size) { std::partition(A, A + size. [](int n) { return n%2==0; }); }`  Done.